# To prove the lower bound of a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am thinking a limit which is very interesting:  For any positive sequence $S_j$ bounded away from zero. we have the following result:
$\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{s_k}{s_l}\geq1$, where $l=[k\log{3}]$, $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$. How can we prove this result?

Comment: If your logs are grown-up (i.e., natural) logs, the statement's false, no?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

If $\log x$ means $\ln x$ then since $\log 3>1$ a sequence $\{s_j\}$ such that $s_j=2^j$ is a counterexample. If $\log x$ means $\log_{10} x$ then since $\log 3<1$ we can consider a subsequence $\{s_{j_k}\}$ of the sequence $\{s_j\}$ such that $j_k=[j_{k+1}\log 3]$. And if 
$\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{s_{j_{k+1}}}{s_{j_k}}<1$ then the sequence $\{s_{j_k}\}$
converges to the zero, which contradicts to the sequence $\{s_j\}$ is bounded away from the zero.